# Image background in bar charts using bokeh (python)

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I have a basic bar chart with the x-axis having categorical values of countries. I want to give each bar, an image background of the country's flag, to make the chart more appealing also to eliminate the x-axis labels. I am currently using bokeh for my charts and I dont think it is possible via this. Any ideas for the same, maybe some other python libraries which might do the trick?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with Bokeh, but you will have to use `image_rgba` or `image_url` functions instead of `vbar` or whatever you're using now.

Comment: Custom hatch pattern is a possibility with vbar, if some tiling is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so for the replies :*). Ill give it a shot and reply back in a day. If you guys have read this comment, can you please tell me which visualization library do you prefer? Just a little on that will help me, since I have just started my journey with data visualization